# Where inside JOIN ON clause?

Tags: mysql

If I have the following tables:

table_a

```
id   |   name  |tbl_b_key| status
-----+---------+---------+--------
0    |    a    |    1    |    0
1    |    b    |    2    |    0
2    |    c    |    3    |    1
```

table_b

```
id   |  type   | status
-----+---------+---------
0    |    a    |    0
1    |    b    |    0
2    |    b    |    1
3    |    a    |    1
```

Is there any difference in terms of performance between these two queries?

```
SELECT table_a.name, table_b.type FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON (table_a.status = table_b.status AND table_b.type = a);

SELECT table_a.name, table_b.type FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON (table_a.status = table_b.status) WHERE table_b.type = a;
```

My understanding is the first query would be faster, as it first reduces the amount of rows being joined whereas the second query does the join then performs the where. Or is there no real difference between the two?

EDIT: As pointed out I made a mistake in my first query, fixed now.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say? Better still, what does EXPLAIN EXTENDED followeg by SHOW WARNINGS; say??

Comment: The first should be a syntax error, do you mean `... ON (table_a.status = table_b.status AND table_b.type = a)`?

Comment: @mata: made a fix there, you were correct.

Comment: @Strawberry: I never knew about this, very handy. Here's a useful guide for those looking to learn more https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: MySQL [combines the conditions from the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) and applies them as early as possible to reduce the amount of data it processes. Your two queries are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries are equivalent. There's no difference.

---

When you have two valid queries you want to compare, you can run an `EXPLAIN` on each to see the execution plan that MySQL will use.

And you can execute each query to measure the performance. (Run each query several times, bypassing the MySQL query cache,measure the elapsed time for each execution, and throw out the time for the first execution.)

---

In general, MySQL will ignore superfluous parens. A predicate is a predicate is a predicate. It doesn't matter if it's in a WHERE clause or in the ON clause of an INNER JOIN condition. MySQL sees it the same

MySQL sees all of these forms as equivalent:

```
  ... a JOIN b  ON   a.foo = b.foo   AND  b.bar = '1'  WHERE ...

  ... a JOIN b  ON  (a.foo = b.foo   AND  b.bar = '1') WHERE ...

  ... a JOIN b  ON   a.foo = b.foo  WHERE b.bar = '1'   AND  ...

  ... a JOIN b  ON  (a.foo = b.foo) WHERE b.bar = '1'   AND  ...

  ... a JOIN b WHERE a.foo = b.foo   AND  b.bar = '1'   AND  ...
```

We can run `EXPLAIN` on all of those different forms, and we will see the exact *same* execution plan. We don't expect any difference in performance.

(With an *outer* join, there's a difference between a predicates in the ON clause and in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown. I've come across this article to help explain the EXPLAIN command. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Have you any other resources that might help in learning more about this topic?

Comment: The real power of EXPLAIN is in understanding the operations that the MySQL optimizer can perform, and what SQL constructs influence or prohibit those operations.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html